# MySQL: What does event `/io/table/sql/handler` mean?

Tags: mysql

Yesterday I experienced a MySQL incident

- the load was extremely high
- All select statements takes more than 3 times time than usual.
- All insert statements takes 10+ times time than usual.

The MySQL performance monitor tool shows:

1. there are lots of `/io/table/sql/handler` has been generated during the period of incident.
2. lots of active threads within the period of incident.
3. lots of blocked thread within the period of incident.

### Questions

1. What does `/io/table/sql/handler` mean?
2. Do you know the possible root cause?

[image]

Comment: Starting about 3am, there was at least one nasty query running.  Or perhaps lots.  Find them and let's discuss them.  Maybe an `ALTER`, maybe a dump, maybe some complex `SELECT`.  The slowlog, if on, would have caught it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From documentation of solorwinds

> `.../sql/handler` = work has been delegated to a storage engine
>
> examples:
>
> - io/table/sql/handler = storage engine is processing an I/O request against a table
> - lock/table/sql/handler = storage engine is processing a table lock operation

### Reference

1. See the MySQL reference manual for more information on Wait Instrument naming (look at the section for "Wait Instrumented Components"):

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-instrument-naming.html